# Changing background color with fade animation on scroll in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

Is there any way to implement changing background color with **fade** animation on scroll in React? I am able to achieve background change effect on scroll, but I am unable to add fading effect.

```
import React from "react";

export default class ScrollBackground extends React.Component {
  state = {
    bgcolor: "black",
    color: "white",
  };

  listenScrollEvent = (e) => {
    if (window.scrollY < 5300) {
      return this.setState({
        bgcolor: "black",
        color: "white",
        opacity: 1 - window.scrollY / 5300,
      });
    } else {
      return this.setState({ bgcolor: "white", color: "black", opacity: 0 });
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.listenScrollEvent);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          background: this.state.bgcolor,
          color: this.state.color,
          height: "800px",
        }}
      >
        <div id="header">
          <h1>fsefd</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="section_1" className="section">
          This is section 1
        </div>

        <div id="section_2" className="section">
          This is section 2
        </div>
        <div id="section_5" className="section">
          This is section 5
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @AjeetShah, for your reference i have added my code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#examples), e.g.: `transition: "background-color 0.5s ease"`. to create fading effect.

> CSS transitions provide a way to control animation **speed** when changing CSS properties. Instead of having property changes take effect immediately, you can cause the changes in a property to **take place over a period of time**.

> For example, if you change the color of an element from white to
> black, usually the change is instantaneous. With CSS transitions
> enabled, changes occur at time intervals that follow an acceleration
> curve, all of which can be customized.

Also, don't forget to use [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce). **Demo**:

```js
const { debounce } = _;
const { Component } = React;

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    bgcolor: "black",
    color: "white",
  };

  listenScrollEvent = debounce((e) => {
    if (window.scrollY < 400) {
      return this.setState({
        bgcolor: "black",
        color: "white",
        opacity: 1 - window.scrollY / 5300,
      });
    } else {
      return this.setState({ bgcolor: "white", color: "black", opacity: 0 });
    }
  }, 50);

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.listenScrollEvent);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.listenScrollEvent);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          background: this.state.bgcolor,
          transition: "background-color 0.5s ease",
          color: this.state.color,
          height: 1000,
        }}
      >
        <div id="header">
          <h1>fsefd</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="section_1" className="section">
          This is section 1
        </div>

        <div id="section_2" className="section">
          This is section 2
        </div>
        <div id="section_5" className="section">
          This is section 5
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```